# Error Playing video from server with MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

I try to play a video on the server with this code. I have a error.

```
//Play the video from server
    - (IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender;
    {
        NNSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString: aVideo.urlVideo];
NSLog(@"URLVIDEO %@", url);
MPMoviePlayerController *VideoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL: url];
[VideoPlayer play];      
    }
```

//Console

```
URLVIDEO http://147.83.74.180/videos/low/ElTemps-index.m3u8
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Content URL must not be nil.'
```

aVideo.urlVideo is defined on the Video class and it gets a value when I parse an xml file

```
//Video.h
NSString urlVideo;

//XMLParser.m
    [aVideo setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName]; //here i add the string
```

If I do this I can play the video:

```
NSString *videoURL = @"http://147.83.74.180/videos/low/ElTemps-index.m3u8";
    MPMoviePlayerController *VideoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoURL]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aVideo.urlVideo isn't a valid URL string.  It is the NSURL that is nil.

Comment: If we don't know what the string is, we can't comment on it.

Comment: You need to check why contentURL is nil.  It could be because the string you pass is invalid - you should now check if it was released, and try logging the NSURL separately.

Comment: I don't know why the string is invalid (see my test on the question). And I also try to log the NSULR separately and the problem persist.

Comment: I did see the NSLog; but that doesn't tell you if the string was autoreleased or not, which could cause the problem.  See my previous comment.

Comment: In Video.m I release urlVideo and I also release aVideo on dealloc method, do you refer on this? But I don't know how can i check it....

Comment: I use this NSURL *url = [URLWithString: acVideo.urlVideo]; NSLog(@"URL %@", url); NSLog(@"URLVIDEO %@", acVideo.urlVideo); acVideo.urlVideo has the correct value, but url is null. What's wrong?

Comment: Ideally we should see how you are allocating and releasing urlVideo (and aVideo), that is the most likely source of your problem.

Comment: Solved. The code is ok. The problem was that the string that I try to convert to NSurl has a space before the first letter. thanks for your help!